# $\int \frac{\exp (z)(\sin(3z)}{(z^2-2)(z^2)} dz$ on $|z|=1$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

So I need to calculate 
\begin{equation*}
\int \frac{\exp(z) \sin(3z)}{(z^2-2)z^2} \, dz~\text{on}~|z|=1. 
\end{equation*}
So I have found the singularities and residues and observed that the singularities $2^{1/2}$, $-2^{1/2}$ (the other singularity is $0$) lie outside of the radius we are looking at. My thoughts were to split in to partial fractions and the integral of the fractions corresponding with these singularities would be zero by Cauchy-Goursat theorem. But I'm unsure how to proceed with the partial fractions as my attempts keep failing. Is this even the right approach?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a singularity - a pole of order one since $\sin (3z) =O(z)$ - inside $|z|=1$.

Comment: Why do you write z^{^{2}} where z^2 will serve? (I changed it, and I also changed $sin$ to $\sin$.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Taylor expansion of $\sin(3z)$

$$\sin(3z)=3z+a_1z^3+\cdots$$

Divide it by $z^2$

$$\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2}=3/z+a_1z+\cdots$$

So, you see, we have a residue at $z=0$

Insert $z=0$ to the rest of the function, and multiply with the $3$ we get from the Taylor expansion, we will have $-\frac32$

Using the residue theorem, we get our answer: $$-3i\pi$$

Comment: What did you mean by multiply by 3? Thanks

Comment: Look at the first term in the taylor expansion of $\sin (3z)/z^2$. That is our simple pole. Its coefficient is 3. But, in the original integral, we have other terms multiplying that $\frac3z$. So we evaluate those at $z=0$ and multiply it with $\frac3z$ to get the coefficient of $\frac1z$

Comment: so is the residue 3? or -3/2?

Comment: And what would we do if we had more than one singularity in the region?

Comment: I focused on the "problematic" part of the integral, which was $\sin(3z)/z^2$. The rest of the integral, is simply a constant at $z=0$, that constant is $exp(0)/(0-2)=-1/2$. So our overall residue will be the product of $-1/2$ and $3$. So our residue is $-3/2$. Which means the value of the integral will be $-\frac32 2 \pi i=-3i\pi$

Comment: If there are more singularities, you'd have to notice them and do this process on each of those points.

Comment: Imagine if the original function was multiplied by two and we had $$\int 2\frac{\exp(z) \sin(3z)}{(z^2-2)z^2} \, dz$$Surely that 2 would somehow need to affect our result. Keep in mind that we are evaluating our function at $z=0$, at that point, the rest of the function is also a constant value, which we take into consideration (by multiplying)

Comment: So if our radius was 3 then would we need to do partial fractions? Thanks

Comment: The limit evaluation Dr. MV has showed will be easier then partial fraction (but partial fraction will also work) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles

Comment: If we had two singularities in the radius would we need to do the partial fractrions?

Comment: it would be one of several ways to do it

Comment: Would there be a way to adapt this method above?

Comment: Partial fraction expansion is how you adapt this method to multiple poles.

Comment: why is it that we expand sin(z) and not exp(z)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a pole of order one at $z=0$.  So, by the residue theorem, that residue is given by

$$\lim_{z \to 0}z\frac{e^{z}\sin(3z)}{(z^2-2)z^2}=-\frac{3}{2}$$

and the integral is $2\pi i \times (-3/2)=-i3\pi$

Comment: How do we know it is a pole?